# Commodore SX-64 White screen

Tags: commodore-64, troubleshooting

I recently acquired a Commodore SX-64.  It powers on, but the CRT just displays a white screen.  I dont have a test cartridge yet, not that it would help as thereis no display.   I havent tried an external monitor yet, but I will.  I was just curious, assuming its just the display, is there a command I can type that would play a sound?  Then I could tell its booting and I need to fix the CRT.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Just in case you are unaware, there are CRT controls hidden behind the panel on the right side. There's also a floppy reset button and volume control. I don't suspect this will fix your display but might change what is shown.
2. Shortest command I'm aware of to make sound output:

   ```
   10 POKE 54296,15:POKE 54296,0:GOTO 10
   RUN
   ```

Comment: Thanks.  Ill try this when I get off of work.  Im hoping its just the built-in CRT.

Comment: Would changing the volume register produce audible clicks in all SID versions for all plausible power-on states?  Otherwise, I would think plugging an audio amplifier set for low volume into the video output and listening for the sound to change a couple of times when the system is switched on would be a good test.